# Characteristics or Preferences of Age Groups When Learning/Acquiring a Language

Tags: english

I've been looking for some research studies to get into more depth about the characteristics of age groups when learning a language. My main focus is on ages of 17 and 18 (basically, when teenagers turn into young adults).

For example, somewhere in the internet I have read that their institution prioritises collaborative teaching, or creating as much interaction as possible because students at this age (pedagogically) wants to interact with each other and adapts a social learning environment easily.

I've tried many search queries on Google Scholar but can't say I found something useful. I want to stay away from the CEFR because I want some real evidence.

Any kind of help would be much appreciated. You'd make me extra happy if you can provide article titles or links.

Thank you.

Comment: this seems to belong on languagelearning.SE although, the existence of all the tags you added lends credence to the question here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about language learning and should be on [languagelearning.se]